# How do I end a voicemail call?

Tags: voicemail

Apologies if this is an elementary question.

I have called up the voicemail service and I listen to the first message; I'm then invited to press a key to save, delete, and so forth, but the screen has gone blank and there is no key to press. How do I recover the keyboard so that I can select an option?

A second problem then presented itself; that not only is there no key to select an option, there is no key to end the call either. The only way I could do this was to take the battery out of the back.

This can't be what the designer intended, but there is no guidance given any of the manuals I have been able to find.

Can anyone give me a pointer to an idiot's guide?

Edit: It is a Samsung Galaxy (can't say what model number), and it has no protective devices attached to it.

Comment: Welcome to http://android.stackexchange.com. Can you specify the device you have (brand and model)?

Comment: "The only way I could do this was to take the battery out" - do you not even have a power button?

Comment: Do you have a screen protector on your phone?

Comment: @Zuul, thank you. I've added the make to the question.

Comment: @w3d, no, it is mother-naked. It is just that I am being asked to press buttons on a blank screen.

Comment: @BrianHooper Has this always been the case since you had the phone, or is this recent?

Comment: @Zuul, I don't believe I've ever called the voicemail with it before; I got a text saying "you have bazillions of messages" and thought I'd better do something about it.

Comment: @BrianHooper Do you use any special app to call the voicemail? or do your just dial the voicemail like a regular call?

Comment: It sounds like your screen simply turned off (possibly due to the proximity sensor) - pressing the power button typically turns it back on.

Comment: @Zuul, no, I just call it as a normal call. That's why I was somewhat surprised by the difficulties I'm having.

Comment: @eldarerathis Answered just that. Don't believe to be anything else...

Comment: @eldarerathis, that might be it. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By what you describe, this is more likely to be related with the proximity sensor.

It is located at the top right corner of your screen, outside of the touch area.

If anything is blocking that sensor, the screen goes black. This happens to prevent the users face from touching anything on the screen during a call.

What works for me, is either using the home button or the power button to bring the screen back on.

Comment: Righto. I do this, and the front screen comes up with all the usual app buttons, and the voicemail call burbling along in the background. So I guess I need to reconnect to that call somehow. I'll go away and try to work that one out. Thank you.